# GCC SFINAE error on const vector?

Tags: c++, gcc, sfinae

This block of code detects the `std::vector<T>::push_back` method via SFINAE but in gcc previous to 4.9 series don't work for ***const*** vector as you can see if try [this online compiler](https://godbolt.org/g/tiS94w). It only work since 4.9 series. I try to find what solves this problem on [release notes](https://gcc.gnu.org/gcc-4.9/changes.html) but I cant locate it. Which changes solves it?

```
#include <vector>

template <typename Type, typename Return, typename P1, Return (Type::*Pointer)(P1)> struct S1PMemberMethod { };

template <typename T> struct SMemberMethodChecker
{
    template <typename Type> static char HasReferencePushBackMethod(S1PMemberMethod<Type, void, const typename Type::value_type &, &Type::push_back> *);
    template <typename Type> static long HasReferencePushBackMethod(...);
    template <typename Type> static char HasPushBackMethod(S1PMemberMethod<Type, void, typename Type::value_type, &Type::push_back> *);
    template <typename Type> static long HasPushBackMethod(...);

    static const bool HAS_PUSH_BACK_METHOD = ((sizeof(HasReferencePushBackMethod<T>(0)) == sizeof(char)) || (sizeof(HasPushBackMethod<T>(0)) == sizeof(char)));
};

int main()
{
    // Compiler error when push_back is not detected
    int A[ SMemberMethodChecker< const std::vector<int> >::HAS_PUSH_BACK_METHOD - 1 ];
}
```

Comment: The link "this online compiler" links to the default code of compiler explorer.

Comment: @Oliv link solved

Comment: In v4.9 with -std=c++11 option the code compile, but not in v4.8. So the fact it compiles is not related to a change in the language but to a bug fix or a completion of the language support. Finding documentation for it is certainly difficult.

Comment: @Oliv c++11 flag not needed it work without it on v4.9

Comment: The point was only to demonstrate that it is independent of the standard version. So the modification of behaviour does not come from a modification of the standard and/or of the default standard used by GCC. If I ware you I would give up looking for a documentation of this change.

Comment: If you want, you can verify that @Oliv is right by using Clang compiler. It works for me with Clang 3.4.1